# JQUERY проверить, что у всех input в div отсутствует фокус

Tags: jquery, jquery-form, focus

```html
<div class="jqx-clear jqx-position-absolute jqx-widget-header" id="addrowjqxgrid" tabindex="-1" style="width: 870px; height: 30px; top: 199px;">
  <div style="z-index: 299; position: relative !important; height: 30px; width: 872px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-top-width: 1px; box-sizing: border-box; border-right-width: 0px;" id="addnewrowbottom.jqxgrid" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-grid-cell-add-new-row jqx-grid-cell-filter-row">
    <div style="position: relative; height: 30px; max-height: 30px; width: 872px;" id="row000jqxgrid">
      <div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; height: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 17; width: 50px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-grid-cell-add-new-row jqx-grid-cell-filter-row">
        <input style="box-sizing: border-box; padding-right: 4px; padding-left: 4px; border: none; text-align: left; width: 100%; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; max-height: 30px; margin: 0px;" autocomplete="off" type="textarea" id="jqxWidget6e3173cb"
        class="jqx-widget jqx-input jqx-widget-content jqx-enableselect jqx-grid-cell-add-new-row" placeholder=" № п/п">
      </div>
      ...
      </
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста,
использую библиотеку jqxWidjets для вывода строк из БД в виде таблиц.
Выше часть структуры, которая создается автоматом. 
Контейнер id="addrowjqxgrid" содержит еще несколько таких же инпутов. 
Выглядит как строка инпутов внизу таблицы, в которой пользователь может добавлять данные для добавления новой строки. 
Как добиться того, чтобы, после того, как пользователь начнет вводит данные в этот ряд, строка добавлялась в БД тогда, когда он кликнет вне этого ряда, но не тогда, когда кликнет на другой инпут?
спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="inputs">
   <input type="text" value="" placeholder="123" />
   <input type="text" value="" placeholder="123" />
   <input type="text" value="" placeholder="123" />
   <input type="text" value="" placeholder="123" />
   <input type="text" value="" placeholder="123" />
</div>

$('div#inputs input:not(:focus)');// Вернет jQuery массив инпутов вне фокуса
```

Comment: $("#addrowjqxgrid input").on("blur",  function () {
                            console.dir( $("#addrowjqxgrid input:not(:focus)") );
                        });
@user190134, код выше в момент нахождения в каком-либо инпуте дает одинаковые массивы по клику на другой инпут и в произвольном месте страницы

Comment: Ясное дело, вы же blur отслеживаете. Поменяйте blur на focus, тогда и увидите результат. Вы взяли элемент в фокус - стало 4 к примеру, а когда вы отслеживаете blur - фокус снимается, элементов опять 5 не в фокусе, и вы уже проверяете сколько элементов.

Comment: действительно, спасибо, но все равно не могу понять как с помощью этого решить задачу - как понять с помощью события, нахожусь я в другом инпуте или вне инпутов

Comment: Когда отлавливаете события - внутри функции $(this) - будет ссылаться на инпут на котором сработало событие. Вот это и будет этот инпут. Я не понимаю вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```
                        var isCalendar = !!~( $(event.target).parents().map(function () {
                            return this.id;
                        }).get().join()).indexOf("calendarjqxWidget"); 

                        var isListbox = !!~($(event.target).parents().map(function () {
                            return this.id;
                        }).get().join()).indexOf("listBox"); 

                        var isInput = !!$(event.target).closest("#addrowjqxgrid").length; 

                        if (wasInputClicked) { 
                            if (isItInput || isItListbox || isItCalendar) return; // если был, то мы еще редактируем everpresentrow
                            console.log("добавляем ряд!");

                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }

                        wasInputClicked = isInput || isListbox || isCalendar;
// Проблема еще была в том, что в двух инпутах были встроенные виджеты: выпадающий список и календарь, которые не входили в контейнер и не являлись инпутами, но вот так удалось решить
```